# Show that f is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_4(t)$, $t$ transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_4$.

Tags: galois-theory

I am trying to show that $f=x^9-t$ is irreducible in $K[x]$, where $K=\Bbb F_4(t)$ with $t$ transcendental over $\Bbb{F}_4$. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks.

How do we determine the degree of the splitting field of $f$ over $K$?

Comment: Is $K=\Bbb F_4(x)$? The question is not clear, and $K$ is not specified, but it cannot contain the transcendental element $t$, or else $K[t]$ makes no sense. Also saying $f(x)=...$ in $K[t]$ is incongruous. Or did you maybe mean to write $f\in K[x]$ instead, where $K=\Bbb F_4(t)$?

Comment: I will be **bold** and edit the question so as to make sense, with $f\in K[x]$ and $K=\Bbb F_4(t)$; just revert the edit if I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the image in $(\Bbb F_4[t]/\langle t\rangle)[x]$ will be $x^9$.  Therefore, any factorization over $\Bbb F_4[t]$ will lead to a factorization of $x^9$ under the coefficient-wise quotient map, which might also be viewed as evaluation at $t = 0$.  You should be able to make progress from here, one final hint is to look at a proof of Eisenstein's criterion for polynomials with integer coefficients since the method is analogous.

(You need to use an appropriate form of Gauss' lemma to go from irreducibility over $\Bbb F_4[t,x]$ to irreducibility over $\Bbb F_4(t)[x]$, if you need that result.)

I'm going to assume that you want the degree of the splitting field over $\Bbb F_4(t)$, since the degree over $\Bbb F_4$ will be infinite.  The polynomial will split provided two things are true:

1. There must be at least one root to $x^9 - t$.
2. There must be a primitive $9$-th root of unity.

I will leave it to you to determine the degree of the extensions necessary to establish these facts.